# How to make large regex patterns in Java?

Tags: java, html, regex

I'm trying to parse(steal) a lot of information from a HTML page. And a lot of information is in blocks. like: username: 1.age 2.gender 3.country etc. It's a very large block and therefore my regex  pattern is huge. All of my regex development tools have a single line for the pattern, and a textbox for the text. It makes developing these kind of large patterns impossible. What am I suppose to do to develop large regex patterns or do I avoid them?

Comment: HTML pages are basically a DOM strucure. So better use a DOM parser instead of regex to get the desired info.

Comment: I'm starting to not care about holded questions and downvotes. this is just so annoying. I got my answer anyways. heh~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML pages are basically a valid DOM strucure. So better use a DOM parser instead of regex to get the desired info. You can explore [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) : Java HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

use the parsing rules described for HTML to generate the DOM trees from text/html resources. Together, these rules define what is referred to as the HTML parser.